# What is best way of JSON parsing in Android?

Tags: android

What is best way of parsing JSON in android? Either parsing normally or using GSON library? What are advantages and disadvantages with GSON library over manual parsing.?

Comment: Have you looked at https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ ?

Comment: Jackson library is fastest for parsing json.
http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't waste your time parsing manually, use the library that comes with Android SDK: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html.

GSON does not only parse JSON, it also creates objects for you depending on the content of the JSON, and also does the viceversa: converting a Java object into JSON. Maybe you will prefer the first option.

Answer (score 3):

I'm use [GSON](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/&ei=-EiYUquXCavc4wSH04HIBQ&usg=AFQjCNGGFFMez8-PfFoEQP93a7eHFY8ssA&sig2=-cWEEaCZ0VbO1AR4dJ3a3A&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bGE) library for serialize and deserealize

Answer (score 2):

Are you confident you can implement the JSON standard correctly yourself? Are you eager to reinvent hot water? Then by all means, do it manually.

Reminder: `{"\"":"\\\"},{\\\":"}` is valid JSON. Good luck.